# Send SSRS dataset parameter options to web page

Tags: html, reporting-services, parameters, dataset

I am trying to implement an HTML page that displays embedded reports with IFrame and I need the report parameters to be displayed on the HTML page and not in the report (because they are ugly).

Is there any way to use the reports dataset or something else to pass the parameters to the web page, when the page is generated or is the only way to do this by making backend SQL-queries and generating the parameter selectors based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Getting parameters out

Your option would be to build a web application that communicates with the SQL Server Reporting Services by SOAP. This can allow you to programmatically load the parameters from a report and handle them in your web application (like display them on your web page). This can be written in a language of your choosing as long as it supports SOAP and Web services to consume the WSDL. You can see the reference article for consuming WSDL here: [Accessing the SOAP API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx).

The methods required to achieve your goal are listed here: [Report Parameters Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155118.aspx).

### Getting data back in

You can pass report parameters within a URL. The standard method is to append `&ParameterName=Value` onto the end of the URL. However, to do so the URL you construct must adhere to specific structure:

```
http://hostname/ReportServer?/RootDirectory/SubFolder/ReportName.rdl&ParamaterName=Value
```

You can pass more than one parameter into a URL by simply appending more after the first. For more detailed information please see the Microsoft article: [Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms155391.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I did not even think about SOAP -solution. I also found out that you can get shared datset ingo with XML.  Example XML http://localhost/reportserver/?/DataSet1&rs:command=GetShareddatasetDefinition More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx#bkmk_reportserver

Comment: That's very cool. I didn't know you could extract a shared dataset definition by a passed URL command. The only problem is your reports would depend on having shared datasets rather than embedded ones.